Why does 100F feel hot?
Why does an outside temperature that corresponds to my natural body temperature feel hot?
Shouldn’t it feel just right?

Hi Dennis, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the help center and this meta post, this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

As someone who has lived in both very hot and very cold climates, I can tell you that what feels hot (or cold) is very subjective and changes as you get acclimated. There are many places in the world where people would find 100F quite comfortable. Also, consider physics. How well would your car's cooling system work if the ambient temperature was close to the engine's temperature? How would you cool that engine?  These are some things your research might want to focus on.

It doesn't feel "just right" because our bodies generate heat by living and existing, and normally lose that heat to the environment. When we don't lose that heat we feel uncomfortable; when we lose too much heat we also feel uncomfortable.

In case you're still following this, it's exactly analogous to why water at 72° feels cold when air at the same temperature feels just right. It involves a "micro-climate", if you will, around the body (the term is usually used with cells, but it works here, too.) I once asked this question, so I know the confusion.)

FWIW the tips of your fingers at rather at somewhere around 90 F, not 100 F. Most of your skin is, which is why thermometers have to be in contact with special places to accurately report body temperature.

True. The tip of my finger is 89 F. So is my forearm skin.
